# How do I execute more code after closing a PyQt window?

Tags: python, pyqt

Here's an example below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
    print "you just closed the pyqt window!!! you are awesome!!!"
```

The print statement above doesn't seem to get executed while the window is open or after I close the window. I want it to print after I close the window.

Comment: I assume there is code to actually put something on the screen?

Comment: There is more code. And it actually does print the statement after opening the window, but I want it to print the statement only after the user closes the window.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do that by redefining the `closeEvent` method, like this:

```
class YourMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    (...)

    def closeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow, self).closeEvent(*args, **kwargs)
        print "you just closed the pyqt window!!! you are awesome!!!"
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I think this is close to what I need. It looks like you are calling closeEvent inside the definition of closeEvent. I must not understand what is going on here. Can you direct me to more examples using super and closeEvent?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. I redefine `closeEvent` to include your print statement but I also include the original `closeEvent` because I don't want to miss the things it does originally.
Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super
Nice explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will check out those links.

Comment: I tried your solution above and it worked. The key is to create a subclass of the QtGui.QMainWindow and edit its closeEvent function so that it also executes the print statement (or, in my case, other code ;) ) after the window is closed. Thanks again, I also learned about subclasses today!

Answer (score 3):

Usually most PyQt applications have such lines in main:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myclass = MyClass()
myclass.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What you can do is define a function that does all the above, and then do whatever you want after the call to app.exec_():

```
def appExec():
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  # and so on until we reach:
  app.exec_()
  print("my message...")
  # other work...
```

All what you would have in main is:

```
sys.exit(appExec())
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works correctly for me (the final print statement is executed):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
win.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
    print "you just closed the pyqt window!!! you are awesome!!!"
```

Comment: This does print the statement after opening the window, but I want it to print the statement only after the user closes the window.

Comment: Take out the second `if` statement to force the event loop to run.